# ProcessBuilder does not work?

Tags: java, windows, runtime.exec, processbuilder

I'm trying add a key register on windows using `ProcessBuilder`. Before I tried `Runtime.getRuntime.exec()` and doesn't work also.

I'm trying this.

```
ProcessBuilder p = new ProcessBuilder("reg add HKCU\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows /v mykey /t REG_SZ /d " + "key_value");
        try {
            p.start();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Registro.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

**The exception is:**

```
GRAVE: null
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "reg add HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows /v mykey /t REG_SZ /d key_value": CreateProcess error=2, O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1042)
    at br.com.iguana.keys.Registro.addChavesRegistro(Registro.java:50)
    at br.com.iguana.keys.Registro.main(Registro.java:158)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:386)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:137)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1023)
    ... 2 more
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Is `reg` available as an executable on your path, as opposed to a shell builtin?

Comment: yep, In cmd I use `reg` and works. I tryied pass `\\Windows\\System32` also and nothing

Comment: Yes, but does `reg.exe` exist as an executable?

Comment: yep...look at: http://i.imgur.com/Mv9G3bO.png

Comment: Separate you commands and parameters as individuals strings, this will reduce the possibility of errors...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Jarrod Roberson is right. You should use:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("reg add HKCU\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows /v mykey /t REG_SZ /d " + "key_value");
```

Comment: If I use: `Runtime.getRuntime.exec()` without `Process` does work, but create `reg.exe` on task monitor and doesn't close this task.

Comment: I'm not sure, but call: `p.destroy()` should stop reg.exe

Comment: yep, I tried `p.destroy();` and `p.destroyForcibly();` but not stopped.

Comment: Ok, now i remember. Without using `p.destroy()` or something similar you can use another cmd command. Always call `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);` and pass as parameter: `taskkill /im reg.exe /f`. The `/f` switch is called to force-kill the process in case it can't be killed normally.

Comment: I solved the problem. I was creating one `Runtime` to add all keys at register. Now, I created one to each and works :) . Thanks a lot.

Comment: Just one more tip, the i'll leave you work :D Instead of create N Runtime to stop reg.exe, create a for loop

Answer (score 4):

[reg is a cmd shell command not an executable](http://ss64.com/nt/reg.html) as in it only exists inside the `cmd.exe` shell environment.